# Allow OpenID to show whose account it is using

Tags: feature-request, bug, stack-overflow-jobs

I manage my dad's bills and email as he is not technically savvy. In any event, I had forgotten that I had recently logged into his email via Gmail. It appears Google keeps track of the most recent account you had logged into via a cookie.

In any event I was going to manage my career account and noticed I had to log in. When I clicked log in, it took me to the screen to either "Log in using OpenID" or register. I chose log in via OpenID as I am using that for SO / Careers.

In any event the next screen took me by surprise. It came up with a button that said click to continue logging into Careers using my OpenID. But it didn't state the email address that OpenID was using. I thought strange, so I just clicked the button. When it logged in I apparently had "registered" to careers via my dad's account. Aha I thought I had forgotten that I was logged into his Gmail account on this machine and now he suddenly has an SO Careers account that I almost most certain he will never use in his life (he is happily retired).

I was just curious if it would be possible for the email / account name to be shown on the screen that allows you to proceed with logging in. Otherwise, you may have others accidentally create accounts based on emails they might have logged into that are part of OpenID.

This is probably an issue with all Stack Exchange sites, not specific to just Careers.

Comment: Are you sure this shouldn't be tagged [tag:feature-request] instead?

Comment: In any event it deserves some attention

Comment: Tyler I added feature request as a tag.

Comment: This actually *is* specific to Careers (and not Jobs), if I understand you correctly. When you're using a login for the first time on a regular Stack Exchange site, it displays a message like *"You are about to create a new account on Example Stack Exchange using a login from Google (example@example.com)"*.

Comment: If that's the case that is good news Jeremy.  However, if that is the case I recommend careers does the same thing and display what email it is going to use otherwise we end up with unnecessary accounts like my father's.

Comment: What is the status of this ticket?